# Конвертировать Doctrine model в массив

Tags: doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Как преобразовать в массив объекты, который получены через getRepository('entity')->findAll();
Нагуглил что это делается через Hydrator, но что то не получается

Answer (score 0):

Вообще есть несколько вариантов. 
Ты можешь в репозитории объявить свой собственный метод который будет возвращать данные в виде масива. 
Например

```
        use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

    /**
     * %Название%Repository
     */
    class %Название%Repository extends EntityRepository{

    public function FindAllArray($val){
       return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
               ->where('id = :val')
               ->setParameter('val', $val)
               ->getQuery()
               ->getArrayresult();
      }
    }
```

Воторой вариант прсто сделать запрос к базе и опять же вызвать метод getArrayresult();

```
$data = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Путь к репозиторию')->createQueryBuilder('q')->where('id = :id')->setParameter('id',$idVal)->getQuery()->getArrayresult();
```

Ещё есть пару вариантов но я полагаю что этих должно быть достаточно.
Вот ссылка на документацию к [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)